# Use jQuery to set value of hidden field in a form and submit the value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using jQuery to assign a value to a hidden field:

```
$('#hidden_id').val("ABC");
```

In my View, I have:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:id => "hidden_id", :val => "") %>
```

How do I pass the value "ABC" from the form to to my Controller (through the param ":val")?

Comment: Have you tried submitting the form

Comment: I did, it does not work

Comment: Your hidden field does not have a `name`

Comment: My DOM code is not in the controller. It is in coffee file.

Comment: Not using angular currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be defining your hidden_field_tag like this

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'hidden', '', id: 'hidden_id' %>

  equivalent to
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden_id" value="">
```

take a look at the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag) for help.